# urllib.request script gets an error even though pycharm sees no mistakes

Tags: python, urllib

so i'm trying to make a script that will download images using url, the problem with the script is it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.3\scratches\scratch_1.py", line 17, in <module>
    url_to_jpg(i,url[0],FILE_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.3\scratches\scratch_1.py", line 6, in url_to_jpg
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full_path)
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

here's my code:

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
def url_to_jpg(i,url,file_path):
    filename='image-{}.jpg'.format(i)
    full_path=''.format(file_path,filename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full_path)
    print('{} saved'.format(filename))

    return None

FILENAME='Book1.csv'
FILE_PATH='C:/Users/My PC/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches'
```

Comment: first use `print(url)` before `urlretrieve(url, ...)` to see what you try to download. Maybe this `url` doesn't exists.

Comment: btw: you could use `print()` also to see values in other variables because `full_path=''.format(file_path,filename)` doesn't look correctly. It should get empty string. Use `full_path = os.path.join(file_path, filename)` or eventually `full_path = file_path + "/" + filename`

Answer (score -1):

Short and sweet solution is

1. pip install requests # use requests module instead of urllib
   Then,

   import requests
   response = requests.get(url)

Now you can perform operations with response

Note:
To get content use response.text or .content
To get in json format use response.json

Comment: Yep! I agree but it depends on the developer.

Comment: I don't think so, because urllib module further produces more error like SSL certificate, etc.

Comment: what would happen if the image in the url has been deleted?